# Is all matter formed from Elementary Particles?

Tags: higgs, elementary-particles

If we could break down all matter, would everything break down to Elementary Particles? Or if nothing existed in the world except Elementary Particles, would they interact with the Higgs Field until they gained enough mass to become complex compounds which would eventually become larger objects or organisms?

Comment: Why aren't there any comments to a down vote? I am new to this site and would appreciate direction instead of silent voting.

Comment: Voting is private and there is no requirement for commenting with a downvote. Both parts are something you'll simply have to get used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world is made of particles, and below is a chart of them. We do believe they are elementary, in the sense that they cannot be decomposed  into "smaller" parts, but please remember that just over 100 years ago, the idea of atoms was not accepted as universally  as it is today, so we may yet be surprised by new discoveries in the elementary  particle field.

[image]

The elementary  particles, again I would stress, elementary as of today's experimental results, are arranged in three families, or generations,  but the bottom row on the chart above, the ones with lowest mass, are the most stable ones, which the higher mass versions eventually decay into.

> Would they interact with the Higgs Field until they gained enough mass to became complex compounds and would eventually become larger objects or organisms?

The short answer to this is no. The amount of mass associated with each of the particles by the Higgs mechanism has no direct bearing on the "clumping" together of elementary particles. Rather than reading Wikipedia,  I would suggest you buy a good popular science book and find out more about the Higgs mechanism.

I cannot yet comment, lacking the reputation points, but as regards down voting,  I think you received down votes because you could have researched this yourself. Personally, I have no big problem with your question, and I am unable to down vote anyway, but other people don't feel the same way. I can see their point however, so perhaps for your next question, you could bear that in mind. :)